# Extracting gzip data from Apache-httpclient without decompression

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm using apache httpclient 4.3.5 to send a request to an upstream server which returns a gzipped response. I need to pass this response AS-IS to a downstream server without any form of decompression. However, httpclient is far too helpful and insists on decompressing the response and I can't find any way of persuading it to stop.

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
CloseableHttpResponse serverResponse = client.execute(serverRequest);
try {
    HttpEntity entity = serverResponse.getEntity();
    downstreamResponse.setStatus(serverResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    for (Header header : serverResponse.getAllHeaders()) {
        downstreamResponse.setHeader(header.getName(), header.getValue());
    }
    entity.writeTo(downstreamResponse.getOutputStream());
    downstreamResponse.flushBuffer();
} finally {
    serverResponse.close();
}
```

I'm sure that there is some way of configuring the client using some form of the construct

```
return HttpClients.custom()
    ....
    .build();
```

but I can't find it. Can the experts please advise?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
        .disableContentCompression()
        .build();
```

Comment: Some explanation would be good. At the moment it is in the Low Quality review queue

Comment: What kind of explanation do you expect? The OP asked specifically for a way to disable content compression, which is precisely what my answer demonstrates

Comment: Your post has been flagged or system-determined such that it has appeared on the Low Quality Review queue, where I saw it. I was offered a button to simply delete it. What I do instead of that, where there is something which is likely to be an answer, is suggest that it contains some explanation. If you prefer to wing it and hope that others don't press Delete, that's fine with me. It may well be out of that queue now, I don't know.

Comment: I have zero interest in playing games here. Anyone who deems my response low quality is welcome to delete it.

Comment: This is appears to correct the issue that I was running into. Thanks Oleg.

Comment: Just to provide explanation the javadoc tells me: **disableContentCompression()** _Disables automatic content **de**compression._ So that clears that up

Comment: This will remove the `Accept-Encoding` header from the request unless set manually, so if OP wants to get the compressed content, he needs to set `Accept-Encoding: gzip` header manually in the request